# Get Both Identifier Column and Another Column with JPA Repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm pretty new to Spring and trying to write a query that returns code and name columns from a db table.

My entity looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouses")
public class Warehouses implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "openingDate")
    private String openingDate;
}
```

And my repository looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "warehouses", collectionResourceRel = "warehouses")
public interface WarehouseEmailsRepository extends JpaRepository<WarehouseEmails, String> {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_WH_ADMIN')")
    @RestResource(path = "codesAndNames", rel = "codesAndNames")
    @Query("Select w.code, w.name From Warehouses w")
    List<Map> findAllCodesAndNames();
}
```

I tried:

1- Example above gives error that says
`Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap!`

2- Not using @Query. Code gave me error for not finding Codes variable in entity.

3- Wrote the Query to return all the data. Since Codes is identifier, it didn't showed up at response.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: is Map one of your classes? if it is it will be enough to change `Select w.code, w.name From Warehouses w` into `Select new path.towards.Map(w.code, w.name) From Warehouses w`. if Map is java.util.Map dunno how to do it.

Comment: It is java.util.Map. Can I do this by defining a new class with only code and name?

Comment: yes you could use a new class